# Populate an array of complex numbers error

Tags: c#, complex-numbers

I have two arrays.  One contains "real" values and the other contains "imaginary" values.  These two arrays need to be combined into an array of complex numbers.  I tried the following:

```
Complex[] complexArray = new Complex[16384];

for (int i = 0; i <16384; i++)
(
    complexArray[i].Real = realArray[i];
    complexArray[i].Imaginary = imaginaryArray[i];
}
```

It doesn't work.  It gives the error: Property or indexer 'System.Numerics.Complex.Real' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only 
I understand that complex numbers are immutable but how then does one create such an array?

Even more so, once I have this array, I want to move values in it.

Comment: probably that struct has a constructor and you need to use constructor to initialize your fields.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 6):

Just use the constructor for `Complex`:

```
Complex[] complexArray = new Complex[16384];
for (int i = 0; i < complexArray.Length; i++)
(
    complexArray[i] = new Complex(realArray[i], imaginaryArray[i]);
}
```

Optionally, you can then reduce the amount of code (slight performance cost) by using LINQ:

```
var complexArray = realArray.Zip(imaginaryArray, (a, b) => new Complex(a, b)).ToArray();
```

To move values in your array, do the same thing as if the values were `int` or `double`:

```
int i = 5;
int j = 7;
// Swap positions i and j
var temp = complex[i];
complex[i] = complex[j];
complex[j] = temp;
```